# Issue covering Test class for class performing Sharepoint integration through sfiles managed package API

Tags: sharepoint

I am getting the below error when I run the test class `ServiceClassTest` (it is a test class used to cover a class performing Sharepoint integration through sfiles managed package API)

> Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts

I am getting this even after setting mock response in the `MockSharepointServiceClass`.

**ServiceClass**:Main salesforce class used to create the integration---Basically this calls method 'getFolderContents' (callout to Sharepoint)
I have setup up the exact sample response I recieved from this method in class `MockSharepointServiceClass`

**ServiceClassTest**-Test class

**MockSharepointServiceClass**:Class used to send dummy callout response

1)ServiceClass(Main APEX class)

```apex
public class ServiceClass {
   @future(callout=true)
   public static void getFolderContents(String ParentFolderId, Id DonorId){
       Map<Id,Sharepoint_Document_Link__c> existingLinkMap = New Map<Id,Sharepoint_Document_Link__c>([Select Id, Name, Document_Link__c, Donation__c from Sharepoint_Document_Link__c where Donation__c =:DonorId]);
       List<Sharepoint_Document_Link__c> newLinks = new List<Sharepoint_Document_Link__c>();
       Set<String> pageContentsNames = new Set<String>();
       Map<String,Sharepoint_Document_Link__c> linksByName = new Map<String, Sharepoint_Document_Link__c>();
       Map<String, Sharepoint_Document_Link__c> linksToDelete = new Map<String, Sharepoint_Document_Link__c>();
       if(!existingLinkMap.isEmpty()){
           for(Sharepoint_Document_Link__c dl : existingLinkMap.values()){
               linksByName.put(dl.Name, dl);
           }  
       }
       //get auth info from the Settings MDT
       fileforcem1__SharePoint_Settings__mdt orgSettings = [SELECT fileforcem1__Named_Credential__c,fileforcem1__Document_Library_Id__c,fileforcem1__Site_Id__c FROM fileforcem1__SharePoint_Settings__mdt WHERE Developername = 'Default' limit 1];
       //get the root folder id for the account object
       fileforcem1__SharePoint_Object_Settings__mdt objectSettings = [SELECT fileforcem1__Root_Folder_Id__c,fileforcem1__Site_Id__c,fileforcem1__Document_Library_Id__c FROM fileforcem1__SharePoint_Object_Settings__mdt WHERE MasterLabel = 'Donation__c' LIMIT 1 ];
       //Initialize the client object
       fileforcem1.ClientApi apiClient = new fileforcem1.ClientApi();
       apiClient.namedCredentialName = orgSettings.fileforcem1__Named_Credential__c;
       apiClient.sharepointSiteId = orgSettings.fileforcem1__Site_Id__c;
       apiClient.documentLibraryId = orgSettings.fileforcem1__Document_Library_Id__c;
       List<fileforcem1.SharepointFileInfo> firstPageContents = apiClient.getFolderContents(ParentFolderId, false);//Callout to Sharepoint
       for(fileforcem1.SharepointFileInfo c : firstPageContents){
           Do some calculation on firstPageContents
       }    
   } 
}
```

2)ServiceClassTest

```apex
@isTest
public class SharepointServiceClassTest {
    @isTest static void testgetFolderContents(){
        
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.Name = 'Test';
        opp.StageName = 'Interested';
        opp.CloseDate = Date.today()+1;
        opp.Pega_Case_ID__c = 'SUB-6071';

        Test.startTest();
        Donation__c don = new Donation__c();
        don.Opportunity__c = opp.Id;
        don.sharepoint_folder_id__c = '01BWEQYAFDTQXHC2JF75GKBRMQKOMLK6O7';
        insert don;
        
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class,new MockSharepointServiceClass());
        SharepointServiceClass.getFolderContents(don.sharepoint_folder_id__c,don.Id);
        test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

3)MockSharepointServiceClass:

```apex
global class MockSharepointServiceClass implements HttpCalloutMock {
    // Implement this interface method
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        String sfr='{"Id":"01BWEQYAFMOYLPH3TODJAJ36GKEJ6DMS7G","Name":"Longfilename.txt","NameWithoutExt":"Longfilename","Type":"File","OpenUrl":"https://uspc.sharepoint.com/sites/Apheleia-DT1DocumentCenter/DS%20Documents/Donations/a0N7h000001KGk4EAG/Longfilename.txt","Format":"txt","ModifiedBy":"Melody Savage (C)","LastModified":"2022-07-04T13:13:32Z","Size":"4 Bytes","Uploading":true}';
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody(sfr);
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Could you let me know if I am missing anything here.

Comment: Is there perhaps an `on insert` trigger on `Donation__c` that calls `ServiceClass.getFolderContents()` or another callout?

Comment: Hi @ThomasTaylor the callout happens on change of a field on Donation(update trigger) and not insert